# Bootstrap 3 row Toggle doesn't align with the row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, toggle

I need to horizontally align a toggle inside a row, using bootstrap 3. I have tried everything. From flexbox, bootstrap classes and force inline styling, yet the thing doesn't seem to care.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row ml10 mr10">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 xs-4">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm mb0 mt10 ml10"
            ng-click="TopicCtrl.getTopicData(sql.data, sql.dataProtection);">
            Run Query
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mb0 mt10 ml10"
            ng-if='TopicCtrl.loading'
            ng-click="TopicCtrl.topicDataStopQuery('Stoped By User')">
            Stop Query
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 xs-8 mr10"
        permission="[lensesCtrl.roles.admin]">
        <div class="pull-right mr10">
            <span><b>Data Protection</b></span>
            <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="TopicCtrl.dataProtection"
                    ng-change="changeDataProtection()">
                <span class="slider round"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code for the toggle:

```
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  margin:6px 0 0;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
```

As far as I can see I am not doing anything wrong here. I just want to align my toggle and span that are on the same div with the buttons. The span is aligned perfectly. The toggle, on the other hand, doesn't. Please help..

Answer (score 0):

When I looked at your code I saw you using class `xs-8` instead of `col-xs-8`. I tried this and this works. Hope this is the answer you where looking for:

https://jsfiddle.net/gvkhx0L8/

Comment: Yes, I had a typo on those 2 classes. That doesn't change the output on larger screen sizes though. I can see that there are some differences between them as well. On my code, the text `data protection` is align perfectly, and the toggle is given a theoretical mragin on the bottom. On inspect there is nothing, no `margin` no `padding`. I want the entire row to align and it doesn;t. Thanks for the spot on the class.